# Check if Value Exists in Database, adding row details to variables and echoing result

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to create a UK Postcode checker for a clients Woocommerce shop.  I have created a table in Wordpress with the cells, Postcode, Town and County.

When a user enters their postcode into a form and clicks submit, I want to check if the postcode exists in our database, and let the user know.

My code is not recognising whether the postcode exists in the database or outputting the town later.

Any help would be most gratefully appreciated.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'vw_postcode_checker';

if (!empty($_POST[postcode]))
{
    $postcode = $_POST[postcode];
    $entry = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$tablename."WHERE postcode =" . $postcode);
    if(count($entry) == 1){
         $id = $entry->id;   //We need this for the delete to work.
         $postcode = $entry->postcode;
         $town = $entry->town;
         $county = $entry->county;
         $confirmed = "Contratulations, we are delivering to" . $town;
         echo $confirmed;
       }
    else {
    $notconfirmed = "Sorry, we are not delivering to your area at this time.";
    echo $notconfirmed;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like that you have an typing error in your code. You declare the variable `table_name` but in the code you use `tablename`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @user141080 I had the table_name declared wrong.  I also missing the '' around the '$postcode', which you do by adding an extra 'at the end of the where clause and  ."'" after the variable.

The code below works now.

```
<?php
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
/*-------------Check Postcode -----------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------*/

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'vw_postcode_checker';

if (!empty($_POST[postcode]))
{
    $postcode = $_POST[postcode];
    $entry = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE postcode = '" . $postcode . "'");
    if (isset($entry))
    {
        $town = $entry->town;
        $county = $entry->county;
        $your_area = $town . ", " . $county;
         $confirmed = "Congratulations, we are delivering to " . $your_area;
         echo $confirmed;
    }
    else
    {
      $notconfirmed = "Sorry, we are not delivering to your area at this time.";
      echo $notconfirmed;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to prepare the SQL query for safe execution. :)